# add pause to align

Tags: beamer, align, pause

[image] 
I want to add some type of \pause to an align expression. i know pause does not work that well with align but what i want to do is:
the statements that you can see in the picture as "1" be visible on the first slide while 2,3,4 are not visible. on the next slide 2 should become visible as well and so on

```
\begin{align*}
  \neg A &\Rightarrow \neg B   &          A &\Rightarrow B         &  A &\Rightarrow \neg B &  \neg A &\Rightarrow \neg C  \\
          B &\Rightarrow \neg A   &  \neg B &\Rightarrow \neg A &  B &\Rightarrow \neg A &          C &\Rightarrow  A 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community added a picture. statements in 1 should be visible on the first slide and 2,3,4 should not be visible. on the next slide statements 1,2 should be visible 3,4 not and so on

Comment: Would having multiple columns in a `columns` environment be an option?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: try with `alignat`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `columns`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column<+->{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        \neg A &\Rightarrow \neg B \\
        B &\Rightarrow \neg A
    \end{align*}
\column<+->{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        A &\Rightarrow B \\
        \neg B &\Rightarrow \neg A
    \end{align*}
\column<+->{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        A &\Rightarrow \neg B \\
        B &\Rightarrow \neg A
    \end{align*}
\column<+->{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        \neg A &\Rightarrow \neg C \\
        C &\Rightarrow A
    \end{align*}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `alignat*`, `array` math environments and `uncover` beamer function:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
    \begin{alignat*}{4}
\begin{array}{rl}
\neg A  & \Rightarrow \neg B \\
B       & \Rightarrow \neg A
\end{array}
    &\uncover<2->{
    \qquad\begin{array}{rl}
        A       & \Rightarrow B \\
        \neg B  & \Rightarrow \neg A
        \end{array}
                }
        &\uncover<3->{
        \qquad\begin{array}{rl}
        A       & \Rightarrow \neg B \\
        \neg B  & \Rightarrow \neg A
              \end{array}
                    }
                &\uncover<4->{
                \qquad\begin{array}{rl}
                \neg A  & \Rightarrow \neg C \\
                C       & \Rightarrow A
                \end{array}
                                }
    \end{alignat*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]